# Bluetooth not working after hot-shutdown of Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Tags: apt, 22.04, bluetooth

There was a hot shutdown of my Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. On rebooting I found that Bluetooth is not working. Before this problem, Bluetooth Manager was installed from Ubuntu Software, but then it became inoperative.

On suggestions from different sources, I removed the above-mentioned Bluetooth Manager, installed BlueZ and uninstalled. Then installed `blueman`, but that was not successful.

I did some troubleshooting without knowing what I was doing and why. Following are some results of those actions:

- Running `blueman-manager` returned the error shown in the screenshot below:

  [image: blueman-manager error]

Adding a USB bluetooth adapter. Got following result.
ashoke@Dell-3470:~$ bluetooth
bluetooth = on

Removing the above adapter got this
ashoke@Dell-3470:~$ bluetooth
bluetooth = none (no device)

- Running `sudo systemctl start bluetooth` returned:

  ```
  Failed to start bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
  See system logs and 'systemctl status bluetooth.service' for details.
  ```
- Running `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service` returned:

  ```
  ○ bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
       Loaded: error (Reason: Unit bluetooth.service failed to load properly, ple>
       Active: inactive (dead)
         Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

  Dec 01 23:28:20 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:28:20 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:28:21 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:28:21 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:28:21 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:30:24 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:30:24 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:30:24 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:33:16 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  Dec 01 23:35:31 Dell-3470 systemd[1]: bluetooth.service: Two services allocated>
  lines 1-15/15 (END)
  ```

I am a novice user of Ubuntu. Can you help me recover from this mess?
I need a tutorial help to solve my problem.

Comment: "*It became inoperative*" should be explained in your logs. Maybe the hardware died. Maybe the log is full of clues about the problem. If you did any troubleshooting, show us. Or are you asking for troubleshooting advice?

Comment: "*was not successful*" could mean that the install failed. Or it could mean the install succeeded, but the bluetooth software did not work for you. Please edit your question to clarify the problem.

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: ashoke@Dell-3470:~$ sudo journalctl  -b 0. Read man journalctl
[sudo] password for ashoke: 
Failed to add match '0.': Invalid argument

Comment: In shot, blueman manager did not work, Inserting a USB bluetooth dongle it detects other TV set-top box but mot mt b;uetoth audio system.

Comment: @bluepearlsky You have run the command suggested by waltinator wrongly. You have to run `sudo journalctl -b 0` (only what is in gray background). From your comment you seem to have run `sudo journalctl -b 0. Read man journalctl` instead.

Comment: Also please see how I have formatted your post and try to apply this formatting to your edits. For more help about formatting your post read here: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting)